# Java Script Webstite Logging : Logging on Kibana,eslastic,splunk or Server Side

Tags: javascript, java, elasticsearch, logging, kibana

How do we log JavaScript based website code, what are the best practices and solution.

Currently we do not have any logging in Javascript code, we started with small but now it has become humongous and very difficult to debug.

Since, it is not best to use console.log developers avoided to use but now it is next to impossible to track what is happening in the code since that code has several sdk calls and different modules within Javascript.

I have spent time to search on this but looking for more insights on what can we use, my findings are on the below lines

> 1. console.log them and send to Kibana,Elastic,Splunk or a VSI and dump log file there.
> 2. Elegant way to do the above approach
> 3. Use some 3rd party logging framework who can handle this efficiently and elegantly

**NOTE:** The site is already developed and it would be tough to go to each of the function and add console.log, also want to persist the logs in server or splunk etc

Comment: :( no reply for Javascript??

Comment: Are you saying you want *client-side* Javascript to log *to the server*?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes sir, might sound stupid but a very genuine ask to handle the chaos.

Or if you can suggest a better alternative to debug like console.log everywhere or something else

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify the question, and to make sure that you recognize what you're asking.  Obviously, if you want client-side components to log to the server then not only do you have to put that logging in, but you also (i) have to use a logging facility that will in fact send log data to the server; (ii) have corresponding support on the server to receive all that log data and stash it somewhere appropriate.  And this may be encumbered by privacy considerations, too.

Comment: I don't think there is any quick or easy solution here, but I'm prepared to be wrong about that.

Comment: so no solution looks like?